# muti-tenant mode in HawkBit Server

Tags: hawkbit

Is there possibility to setup HawBit server in multi-tenant mode ?

I did not find anything in configs and google did not help too
I see in database tables as
| sp_tenant                       |
| sp_tenant_configuration         |

I have addede new records in tables, but hot help